# Outlook and c# application integration

Tags: c#, outlook

I have a c# application that when executed opens outlook,where i have my own custom Addin of associating emails to some particular tasks in my application.

Basically i go through their subject and if I find  a particular pattern I associate it to a task in application.

Now when ever I click on any email inside the inbox,I have a selection_changed event handler associated with it.All works fine till here.

Problem arises when I have two accounts opened up in outlook.
I just want the selection changed event handler for one account only and not for any other accounts.

How can that be achieved in c#.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem you describe is because you have multiple Outlook Explorer windows open, then you'll have to manage the Explorers collection (via a wrapper class) and setup your SelectionChanged event whe the Explorers.NewExplorer event fires for only the Explorer objects that you want to manage events for.

Comment: Hi Eric,I have two accounts configured on outlook.I have somehow got the solutions,please tell me is it the most optimal solution or not.What I am doing is adding a folder change event handler.So whenever their is a folder change I check that which folder of which email account he has switched to,If he is in a folder of lets say xyz@gmail.com,and that not the registered email id for my app,then I don't trigger the selection change event handlers.

Comment: Every Folder has a StoreID property; you can evaluate that against all loaded Store objects in the NameSpace.Stores collection and only process folders for the stores that you want. You can match a particular Store with a particular account via Account.DeliveryStore in NameSpace.Accounts.